# Question on Chernoff bound type probability argument.

Tags: probability, statistics, cryptography

The following result was given in the [research article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1810) ([claim 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHpG7.jpg)) and no justification was provided for the proof. I have presented the claim in simple terms below. Basically, I want to understand what theorems were used and how to prove the following two (To prove) parts.

---

We have two devices $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ far apart. $\mathscr{A}$ takes input $x_i \in \{0,1,2\}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ takes input $y_i \in \{0,1\}$. They both give *random* outputs $a_i, b_i \in \{0,1\}$ respectively for $i$th input.

Uniformly $m$ random input pairs are selected $$I=\{ (x_i,y_i) \mid x_i \in \{0,1,2\}, y_i \in \{0,1\} \text{ for } 1\leq i \leq m\}$$ and outputs are collected in the set $\mathbb{O}$.

Let $C$ denotes the set of inputs such that $(x_i,y_i) = (2,1)$ i.e., $C=\{ (x_i,y_i) \mid x_i = 2, y_i = 1 \}$.
At random for $0 < \gamma <1$, a total of $\gamma m$ $\in \mathbb{N}$ inputs are selected from $I$. Lets denote this set as $B$.

> **To Prove 1:** The randomly chosen set $B$ contains a fraction of at least $\gamma /2$ fractions from the elements of the set $C$, except with probability at most $e^{- \gamma |C| /8}$.

Let $C_B$ denotes the elements of $C$ in the set $B$. If for $C_B$ the outputs satisfies $a_i \neq b_i$ for at most $\eta$ fractions of times. Then

> **To Prove 2:** With probability at least $1-e^{- \gamma |C| /200}$ the total fraction of rounds in $C$ such that $a_i \neq b_i$ is at most $1.1 \eta$.

Comment: Does "Contains a fraction of at least $\gamma/2$ from the elements of the set $C$" mean "$|B \cap C| \ge \frac{\gamma}{2}|C|$"?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes you are right, it means $\gamma /2$ fractions from the set $C$.

Comment: Also, what is $\Pr[a_i \ne b_i]$: is it known, or are we doing some kind of worst-case analysis? (If so, what kind?)

Comment: @MishaLavrov We don't have any information regarding $Pr[a_i \neq b_i]$. For the actual problem, it should be the case that $a_i=b_i$, whenever input belongs to the set $C$. $B$ denotes the test rounds, where we actually check if $a_i=b_i$ for input in $C_B = B \cap C$. And $\eta$ is maximum error allowed (fraction of round in $C_B$ such that above condition is not satisfied.) Then what can we infer about the bigger set $C$, that is given in the (to prove 2).

Comment: In that case, it seems like the result is false as $\Pr[a_i \ne b_i] \to 0$ and simultaneously $\eta \to 0$, if the bound we want does not depend on $\eta$. Intuitively, if errors are very unlikely, it is not very informative that none of them appear in the test cases.

Comment: @MishaLavrov This is given in claim 6 of the paper. Here is the picture for the exact statement https://imgur.com/UUxXe3z . I think they are considering the worst case, If $\eta$ error occurred in $C_B$, then how must error can be there in $C$ and with how much probability.

Comment: I agree that claim 6 in the paper states this; however, the hypotheses I see so far are not enough to conclude it. Is there, for example, some dependency between $\eta$ and $\gamma$ elsewhere in the paper?

Comment: Consider for example the case that $\Pr[a_i \ne b_i] = \eta = \frac1{|C|}$, for large $|C|$. Then with probability around $\frac1{2e}$, there are exactly two (which is $2\eta|C| > 1.1\eta|C|$) rounds in $C$ where $a_i\ne b_i$, and with probability around $(1-\gamma)^2$, neither of them is picked for $C_B$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Following relation is given in the paper $\gamma=\left(C_{\gamma} / \eta^{2}\right) \ln (1 / \varepsilon) / m$ for some universal constant $C_{\gamma}$ and given value $\varepsilon > 0$

Comment: Possibly the reason for the $\eta^2$ in that definition is that the second bound you want has a typo in it and it's meant to have $\gamma \eta$. But it seems annoying to chase down what all the constants are and what we want them to be.

Comment: @MishaLavrov $C_{\gamma}$ may be dependent of $\eta$. (theorem 8)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes it is possible that there is a typo in that paper. Thank you for your explanation and for clearing out my doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4430516/383078) for the inequalities we'll need: if $X$ is either binomial or [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) with mean $\mu$, then:

- for any $\delta \in [0,1]$, we have $\Pr[X \ge (1+\delta)\mu] \le e^{-\frac13 \delta^2\mu}$;
- for any $\delta>0$, we have $\Pr[X \le (1-\delta)\mu] \le e^{-\frac12 \delta^2\mu}$.

### The first bound

This matters, because in the first question, $|B \cap C|$ is a hypergeometric random variable: we are taking $\gamma m$ samples from $I$ **without** replacement, and the probability of success on an individual trial is $p = \frac{|C|}{m}$. (If we were sampling with replacement, the result would be binomial, and the Chernoff-type results for binomials are much more well-known.) The inequality above tells us
$$
   \Pr[|B\cap C| \le (1-\delta)\mu] \le e^{-\frac12 \delta^2 \mu}.
$$
We are taking $\delta = \frac12$ here, and $\mu = \gamma |C|$, so the upper bound is $e^{-\gamma|C|/8}$.

### The second bound

I don't believe $e^{-\gamma |C|/200}$ is possible with the given assumptions, but here's what we can do instead.

Let $D = \{i : a_i \ne b_i\}$. The case we want to avoid is that $|C \cap D| \ge 1.1\eta |C|$ (there are many rounds in $C$ such that $a_i \ne b_i$) but $|B \cap C \cap D| \le \eta |B\cap C|$ (the sample $B$ doesn't notice).

Without further assumptions, we can't say how large $C \cap D$ is, and it's possible that $\Pr[i \in D] > 1.1\eta$, in which case $|C\cap D| \ge 1.1\eta|C|$ is likely. However, we can say that if $|C\cap D| \ge 1.1\eta |C|$, then $|B \cap C \cap D|$ is very likely to also be large.

Let $\gamma'$ be the constant such that $|B\cap C| = \gamma'|C|$; given the event we've already bounded, $\gamma' \ge \frac12\gamma$. Then $B\cap C$ is equally likely to be any subset of $C$ of size $\gamma'|C|$: we are taking $\gamma'|C|$ samples from $C$ without replacement. If a "success" is picking an element of $C \cap D$, then the probability of success is $\ge 1.1\eta$, so the expected number of successes is at least $1.1\eta \cdot \gamma'|C|$. By the Chernoff bound we have,
$$
   \Pr[|B \cap C \cap D| \le \eta \gamma'|C|] \le e^{-\frac12 \cdot (\frac1{11})^2 \cdot 1.1\eta \cdot \gamma'|C|}
$$
which is at most $e^{-\eta \gamma |C|/440}$.

This is worse than the given bound $e^{-\gamma|C|/200}$ in two ways. First, there is a factor of $2$ coming from the bound $\gamma' \ge \frac12\gamma$. But that comes from our first argument, which has a much stronger error term $e^{-\gamma|C|/8}$. The right factor to pick could be more like $\gamma' \ge 0.9\gamma$, which will make the first error term worse, but the second error term better.

Second, there is a dependency on $\eta$ in addition to $\gamma$, which I don't think can be eliminated. I've already said this in the comments, but let me repeat the example: suppose $\Pr[a_i \ne b_i]$ and $\eta$ are both very small, say $\Pr[a_i \ne b_i] = \eta = \frac1{|C|}$. Then as $|C| \to \infty$, $|C\cap D|$ approaches a $\text{Poisson}(1)$ distribution; for example, $|C\cap D| = 2$ with probability about $\frac 2e$. However, $B$ is very likely to miss both elements of $C \cap D|$: the probability of this is roughly $(1-\gamma)^2$. For large $|C|$, $\frac2e \cdot (1-\gamma)^2$ is much larger than $e^{-\gamma|C|/200}$ (but not larger than $e^{-\eta \gamma|C|/200}$).